# Trying to merge two loaded h5 models into a single one

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have two models, A and B, A is not sequential (it is a UNet that computes the mask of an image), and B is sequential (it gives a label to the masked image). I want to merge these two models into a single one, however, I get an error. The models are the following:
[model A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbCUf.jpg)
[model B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiOly.jpg)

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Resizing
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Concatenate

pretrainedmodel_files = ["/kaggle/input/model-neaugmentat/model.h5", "/kaggle/input/clasificare-neaugmentat/model_neaugmentat_clasificare.h5"]

A,B = [tf.keras.models.load_model(filename) for filename in pretrainedmodel_files]

new_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
new_model.add(A)
new_model.add(Resizing(400,400))

combined = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([new_model.output, B.input])

new_model.add(combined)
x = new_model.output
outputs = B(x)
model_merged = tf.keras.Model(A.input, outputs, name = 'merged_model')
model_merged.summary()
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUS0g.png)

**Update**

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Resizing
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Concatenate, Reshape, Permute

input_a = keras.Input(shape=(256,256,1))
input_b = keras.Input(shape=(400,400,3))

x = A(input_a)
y = Resizing(400,400)(x)
x = A(y)
x = Concatenate(axis=3)([y, x])
x = Reshape((-1,400,400))(x)
x = Resizing(3,400)(x)
x = Permute((2,3,1))(x)
x = B(x)

model_merged = tf.keras.Model(input_a, x)
model_merged.summary()
```

[image: single input merged model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combined = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([new_model.output, B.input])

new_model.add(combined)
```

> New model must be a Layer, found a Tensor

You problem is right there. `Concatenate(axis=3)` makes a layer. `([new_model.output, B.input])` calls it and returns a tensor, you can't add tensors top a model, only layers.

It looks like you're trying to add a second input to the Model. You can't do that with the sequential API.  Forget about the Sequential here and use the functional API. It looks like you're trying to do this:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Resizing
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Concatenate

input_a = keras.Input(shape=(256,256,1))
input_b = keras.Input(shape=(400,400,2))

x = A(input_a)
x = Resizing(400,400)(x)

x = Concatenate(axis=3)([x, input_b])
x = B(x)

model_merged = tf.keras.Model([input_a, input_b], x)
model_merged.summary()
```

[image: merged model summary]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried it and now I don't have that error anymore, however, I am not sure that it does what I want it to do. So, I want an image to be "masked" through model A and then classified through model B which takes as input the output from model A, and I want all of this to be in the same model. My code is now updated in the post.

Comment: I want to merge those two models in order to measure their overall accuracy, I'm not interested in outputting the mask (output of model A). I trained them separately but now I want to see how they are together, because I have more variants of the same model (Av1, Av2,..., Bv1, Bv2) and I want to see which combination of model A and B is the most accurate for my dataset.

Comment: "not sure that it does what I want it to do" - I'm pretty sure it's doing what you're describing. It runs an input through A, concats that to input_B, and runs it through B, then it builds a model that returns the output of B. Maybe you want there to be just one input? Then just start with one input, resize as necessary, run it through A, concat to the input, run it through B, return the result of B.

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated the code with the version with a single input.

Comment: Could you also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856072/flow-from-directory-fitting-of-model-yields-valueerror-input-0-is-incompatible) question as well, please?