# flow_from_directory fitting of model yields ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have the following model:

[image]

I tried to fit the model using ImageDataGenerator with flow*_*from_directory and fit_generator, however I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 1), found shape=(None, 400, 400, 1)
```

I used the correct target_size, so I don't know why the error appears. My code is the following:

```
model_merged.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer="adam",
          metrics=['acc'])
train_datagen =ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.25)

#training data
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/kaggle/working/images/',  # Source directory
    target_size=(256, 256),  # Resizes images
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',subset = 'training')

epochs = epochs
#Testing data
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/kaggle/working/images/',
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data
#Model fitting for a number of epochs
history = model_merged.fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch=steps_train,
  epochs=epochs,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = steps_val,
  verbose=1)
```

**Update**

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 32
steps_train = 18
steps_val = 3
img_height = 256
img_width = 256
data_dir='/kaggle/working/images/'
model_merged.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer="adam",
          metrics=['acc'])
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

# scale pixel value between 0 and 1
normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
reshape_layer = Reshape((-1,256,256))
resize_layer = Resizing(1,256)
permute_layer = Permute((2,3,1))

train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (reshape_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (reshape_layer(x), y))
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (resize_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (resize_layer(x), y))
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (permute_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (permute_layer(x), y))


AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

history = model_merged.fit(
  train_ds,
  steps_per_epoch=steps_train,
  epochs=epochs,
  validation_data = val_ds,
  validation_steps = steps_val,
  verbose=1)
```

The error is the same as the one above. I added some new layers in order to change the input layer from (None,256,256,3) to (None,256,256,1), as this was the initial error, but it still doesn't work. I am not sure where the error comes from because the dimensions of the train and validation datasets are correct now.

**Update 2**
[image: new model]
I removed the concatenation layer from the merged model, since I want the output of model A to be passed to the input of model B, however, even with the new merged model the error still appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you open to use the more modern https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

if yes this is a working example close to your code

```
epochs = 32
steps_train = 18
steps_val = 3
img_height = 256
img_width = 256
data_dir='/kaggle/working/images/'
model_merged.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer="adam",
metrics=['acc'])
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
data_dir,
validation_split=0.25,
subset="training",
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
label_mode="categorical",
batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
data_dir,
validation_split=0.25,
subset="validation",
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
label_mode="categorical",
batch_size=batch_size)

# scale pixel value between 0 and 1
normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
reshape_layer = Reshape((-1,256,256))
resize_layer = Resizing(1,256)
permute_layer = Permute((2,3,1))

train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (reshape_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (reshape_layer(x), y))
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (resize_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (resize_layer(x), y))
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (permute_layer(x), y))
val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (permute_layer(x), y))


AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

history = model_merged.fit(
train_ds,
steps_per_epoch=steps_train,
epochs=epochs,
validation_data = val_ds,
validation_steps = steps_val,
verbose=1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried changing the rescale factor and also keeping the default one, but the error is the same, seems like nothing changes.

Comment: Rescale is for the pixel, to have them in [0:1] and not [0:255], sorry this answer is useless, I'll try another one

Comment: @Alexandra I edited my answer maybe it's too far from what you want, sorry I really don't know what's wrong with your code except the use of deprecated functions

Comment: I updated the post with my new approach, it still gives the same error after fixing the train and validation image sizes so I am not sure where it comes from.. I didn't know about image_dataset_from_directory, I am a beginner :) thanks for the idea

Comment: Oh I think I just got it ! In your previous question you ask how to merge the 2 models, but what you want is take the result of A and put it as the input of B ? What you did here is different, as the previous answerer said "t runs an input through A, concats that to input_B, and runs it through B, then it builds a model that returns the output of B" with this model you are suppose to concatenate your image + the result of A to B and not just pass A to B

Comment: Okay so I removed the concatenation layer from the merged model, since I just want the output of model A to be given as input of model B, but it yields the same exact error as before.. I updated the post with the summary of the new merged model. I don't know why I left that concatenation layer there, thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Can you post the full code here ? with the merge of the 2 models, the summary is weird with this connected column, I am not used to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250563/discussion-between-alexandra-and-alexandre-catalano).